# Cannot read property 'kind' of undefined when adding @nestjs/ng-universal

Tags: angular, webstorm, nestjs, angular-universal

Hey I am trying to add  @nestjs/ng-universal for server side rendering to my fresh generated angular project.

I am getting the following error when trying to add the package:

```
$ ng add @nestjs/ng-universal
...
? What is the name of your application? my-project
Cannot read property 'kind' of undefined
```

So what is happening. Its a fresh generated Angular 8 CLI Project. Few weeks ago it worked fine!

Comment: please try a solution from https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/13172#issuecomment-529177249 - does it help?

Comment: Yes that seems to work. `ng add @nestjs/ng-universal --clientProject project-name` then it wants you to install `typescript`. So I installed typescript and run again `ng add @nestjs/ng-universal --clientProject project-name` WORKS! thanks